# Been told washing machine drain too clogged to clean out

Tags: plumbing

Plumber wants to install new drain pipe up through attic and connect with bathroom drain pipe that empties into sewer. It will be hooked to a sump pump to push water up. My main concern is it ok to connect it to the bath drain pipe
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Think I would get another plumber.  This sounds odd.

Comment: I've heard of vandals or p'd-off tenants dumping cement or concrete into drains which makes them impossible to clean out requiring replacement.  But short of that, I can't imagine what's in there that cannot be removed.  Find a better plumber!

Comment: Did the plumber describe the pipe? Was it old galvanized or cast iron?